# Conda install failure with CONNECTION FAILED message

Tags: connection, conda

I'm trying to do an install of `Ipyvolume` with Conda with the command line

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipyvolume
```

But Conda fails with the crucial message:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for URL
>   <http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/ numpy/osx-64/repodata.json>

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the entire output, and please format it using the code formatting